# Retrieving Inner Most If Condition in Text with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file containing the following text (sample nested if, I know it doesn't make sense.):

```
<if string=%fld.plaintiffsSex eql=Male>
    <set field=plaintiffPronoun1 value=[his]>
    <set field=plaintiffPronoun2 value=[he]>
    <set field=plaintiffPronoun3 value=[him]>
<else>
    <if string=%fld.plaintiffsSex eql=Female>
        <set field=plaintiffPronoun1 value=[her]>
        <set field=plaintiffPronoun2 value=[she]>
        <set field=plaintiffPronoun3 value=[her]>
    </if>
</if>
```

Unfortunately, I have to use Regex to get the innermost if statement. I currently have the following Regex, but it's not working as I'd expect. The Regex statement essentially just has to be any if statement that doesn't contain `<if`.

```
// first if that doesn't contain <if to </if>
[\s\S]*(<if[\s\S]*?(?!.*<if)[\s\S]*?<\/if>)
```

See it here http://regexr.com/3e8p7

What I want to capture is just:

```
<if string=%fld.plaintiffsSex eql=Female>
    <set field=plaintiffPronoun1 value=[her]>
    <set field=plaintiffPronoun2 value=[she]>
    <set field=plaintiffPronoun3 value=[her]>
</if>
```

Currently, it gets what I want as Group[1], but I just want it to be the whole match.

Please don't answer with alternative methods/extensions for parsing XML or text.

**EDIT:**

I tried copying and pasting the same thing twice but it still comes up with just one match when it should be two.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm working in C#.

Comment: Post sample output

Comment: In what language / environment?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's Regex. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it matters. *Always indicate which platform you need or want to use (programming language, tool, occasionally even version information). Keep in mind that regex dialects are different; the lowest common denominator will usually be quite different from what is possible and recommended for a tool with a modern, souped-up regex engine.*

Comment: @revo Good to know. I didn't realize it varied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
<if[^<]*(?:<(?!if)[^<]*)*?<\/if>
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bU1pJ7/1)

The idea is to check if there is no opening `<if` tag inside current `if` statement.

**Explanation**:

```
<if         # Match `<if` tag
[^<]*       # Anything up to a `<`
(?:         # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    <(?!if)     # If `<` is not followed by `if` (there is no `if` inside current `if`)
    [^<]*       # Anything up to a `<`
)*?         # End of non-capturing group (a) - repeat current pattern zero or more times (un-greedy)
<\/if>      # Up to closing `</if` tag
```

Comment: What about the following? There should be two matches. https://regex101.com/r/lP0hW5/1

Comment: Then use `g` modifier.

Comment: So a change in input?

Answer (score 2):

```
(<if(?:(?!<if).)*?<\/if>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/yG2cU4/1

- `(` - begin capture group
- `<if` - match exactly `<if`
- `(?:(?!<if).)*?` - Match any number of any single character that is NOT followed by literally `<if`, and do it lazily, meaning that it will match the minimum length that still allows the regex to match.

  - `(?:` - begin a non-capturing group (a group, but the match isn't captured)
  - `(?!<if).` - A negative look-ahead, basically asserts that the content following the character is not `<if`.
  - `)*?` - Repeat any number of times, lazily, so matching minimum possible.
- `<\/if>` - Match literally `</if>`
- `)` - End capture group

You'll need to do a global search (`g` modifier) to match multiple results, and you'll also need `.` to match newlines, which is the `s` modifier.

The resulting match will be captured in capture group 1.

Comment: Revo beat you to it

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<(?!(if\s|else|\/if)).+?>
```